# Grails Spring Security Twitter plugin: 401 unauthorized

Tags: grails, spring-security, twitter, twitter-oauth

I wanted to start playing with [grails spring security twitter plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-twitter) and I've cloned the [github repo of the plugin demo application](https://github.com/splix/grails-twitter-authentication-example).

After setting up a new twitter application and set my consumerKey/consumerSecret properties with the data Twitter gave me, I've run the application (Grails 2.1.1, plugin version 0.5, as in the demo).

The grails app starts and I'm able to see the "sign in with twitter" button. Unfortunately, when I click it, I get the following error:

```
Error 500: Internal Server Error

URI
    /myApp/j_spring_twitter_security_check
Class
    org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException
Message
    401 Unauthorized

Around line 101 of TwitterAuthFilter.groovy

 98:        String url = linkGenerator.link(uri: authFilter, absolute: true)
 99:        log.debug("Back url: $url")
100:
101:        OAuthToken requestToken = oauth.fetchRequestToken(url, null)
102:        request.session.setAttribute(REQUEST_TOKEN, requestToken)
103:        String authorizeUrl = oauth.buildAuthorizeUrl(requestToken.value, (OAuth1Parameters) OAuth1Parameters.NONE)
104:        response.sendRedirect(authorizeUrl)

Around line 49 of TwitterAuthFilter.groovy

47:        String oauthVerifier = request.getParameter("oauth_verifier")
48:        if (oauthVerifier == null || oauthVerifier.length() == 0) {
49:            redirectToTwitter(request, response)
50:            return null
51:        }

Trace

   Line | Method
->> 101 | redirectToTwitter     in TwitterAuthFilter.groovy
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    49 | attemptAuthentication in     ''
|   886 | runTask . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run                   in     ''
^   619 | run . . . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

On my twitter application settings, I've enabled the "*Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter*" option, given *read & write* permissions to the twitter app and created my access token (which I don't specify in my grails app, though).

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you get in console/log at this moment?

Comment: No errors in the console.log. On the server side log, I get pretty much the same message: `Servlet.service() for servlet [default] in context with path [/myApp] threw exception
Message: 401 Unauthorized`

Comment: So, even for the line `log.debug("Back url: $url")` no logs?